# How to create a column based on the min and max of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have two dataframes, one that contains the min and max of latitude and longitude of a grupo of places, and the second that contains the latitude and longitude of a specific place.

**df1**

| group_places | min_lat | max_lat | min_long | max_long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 39.1 | 40.1 | 9.2 | 10.5 |
| B | 38.10 | 39.05 | 8.1 | 9 |
| C | 33.1 | 35.1 | 7.1 | 8 |
| D | 31.1 | 35 | 6.1 | 7 |

**df2**

| place | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f | 34.1 | 7.9 |
| g | 39.2 | 9.8 |
| h | 31.2 | 6.8 |

I need to create a column in df2 that shows the group_places based on the latitude & longitude range in df1. (**latitude and longitude are just an example**)

**df_result**

| place | lat | long | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f | 34.1 | 7.9 | C |
| g | 39.2 | 9.8 | A |
| h | 31.2 | 6.8 | D |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: cross merge and query if your data are not too long.

Comment: Unfortunately, my df1 has 9k rows and df2 25k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data size, the cross-merge data is about 200M rows, so it should be doable:

```
(df2.merge(df1, on='key')
    .query('(min_lat<=lat<=max_lat) and (min_long<=long<=max_long)')
    [['place','lat','long', 'group_places']]
)
```

Output:

```
   place   lat  long group_places
2      f  34.1   7.9           C 
4      g  39.2   9.8           A 
11     h  31.2   6.8           D
```